# Does possible with Log4J on each start of application rewrite file?

Tags: java, file, log4j

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I overwrite a log file in log4j?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965614/how-do-i-overwrite-a-log-file-in-log4j)

My log file is very big after small running time. And also for debug purposes I need frequently restart app. After I only check if there are errors in log. Does it possible configuree log4j.xml (properties) to clear(delete) old log file? Because I sometimes confused - old errors or new.