# Java Log4j overwrite output of FileAppenders

Tags: java, log4j, logfile

I am using Log4j for logging output of my application. 
The log4j.properties files contents the following:

```
    log4j.logger.DEFAULT_LOGGER=INFO,main_log, stdout
    log4j.additivity.DEFAULT_LOGGER = false

    # Direct log messages to a log file
    log4j.appender.main_log=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
    log4j.appender.main_log.File=mainLog.log
    log4j.appender.main_log.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.main_log.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy mm dd HH:mm:ss} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

    # Direct log messages to stdout
    log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
    log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
    log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy mm dd HH:mm:ss} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Currently the following happens. When I start my main method where I call

```
static Logger log = Logger.getLogger("DEFAULT_LOGGER");
log.fatal("Process Logger");
```

it prints the output to stdout and file.log, which is fine. But when I start my application a second time it adds the output to the existing file. But I want to overwrite the log file. Is this possible? (I dont want to use Java for deleting, also I dont want to delete it manually of course) Is there an option in Log4J to tell the logger is to overwrite or the add output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [RollingFileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/RollingFileAppender.html) for this.

Check following SO questions on similar lines:

- [Post One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965614/how-do-i-overwrite-a-log-file-in-log4j)
- [Post Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538278/how-to-keep-single-file-and-overwrite-the-contents-in-the-same-file-using-log4cx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use FileAppender, add log4j.appender.fileAppender.Append=false property to it